# Returned ID from SELECT statement

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I use in my Project the `IfExistsTable` function; in order to see the existence of a table.

For this purpose I use the Select statement as follows.

```
MASQLComm = New SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) AS [RecCount] From sys.tables WHERE name Like '%" & tName & "%'", SQLConn)
RecCount = CInt(MASQLComm.ExecuteScalar)
```

After that I take the number which returned in `RecCount`. Until now the numbers was `1` and `0`

And so I was turn the numbers in `True` or `False`.

Now suddenly the returned number is `2` which I can’t understand what it means.

Comment: Yes Yes Yes You are very much right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number represents the number of tables that match your like statement. For example, if you have the tables

- Widgets
- Products
- WidgetsInProducts

And pass "Widgets" into your query, it's going to match both the table "Widgets" and "WidgetsInProducts". This is not the behavior you want.

To resolve this you need to do an exact match instead of a like as @Alex Aza demonstrated in his answer.

Comment: Yes you have answer in my question. thank you very much I give one

Answer (score 2):

Count return the number of rows in the table. You should not expect it to be 0 or 1 only.

You can argue that there can't be more then one table with one name, but the problem is that your query uses `like '%TableName%'`. So if you have table `MyTable` and `BestTable`, and you want to check if `Table` exits, the result of count will be 2, although there are is no table with such name.

You could update the select statement to look like this:

```
select case when exists(select * from sys.tables where name = 'TableName') then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: Yes I could use that as an alternative approach. But I don't want to change my code; and most of all what is that number? What it represents?

Comment: @Lefteris Gkinis - added more details to my answer. I'm afraid you need to change your query if you want to make it work.

Comment: Yes your answer is most accurate. How can I say ... It is in th right path .... @Chris Pebble giving me the answer I want. Thank yoou very much as well, give you one.

Comment: @Lefteris Gkinis - It is sad. I answered first, provided the explanation and the solution, but you didn't like the answer :(.

Comment: @Alex No No No Please you make me feel very bad now because as I was explain you where in the right path. But the issue here is not the right path but is the "Answer to the Question" OK Please :)

Comment: @Alex the question was "What is this Number" and Not how to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

hi Lefteris Gkinis
if you do not want to change your query you can check your **RecCount** variable accordingly
say

```
if(RecCount == 0)
{
// code what you were using for false condition 
}
else
{
// you got atleast one record 
// and in RecCount  you have number of matching rows
}
```

by this kind of code you are able to show matched row count also.

Comment: @patric. What I have to know was the meaning of the numbers. Which now I have it. I want to thank you very much for your interest to answer.

Comment: @Lefteris Gkinis ... you are most welcome but I thought you want the code to run.. :)